# How to fix this error 'The column 'DistrictID' was specified multiple times for 'piv'

Tags: sql-server, join, pivot-table, inner-join

I want to show the inspector name, inspector post, district and project with inspection done by the inspector according to months for which i'm using pivot but i'm getting 
"The column 'DistrictID' was specified multiple times for 'piv'."  this error...

Please help me to get over this error

```
Declare @SQLQuery nvarchar(MAX)
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TBL1') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #TBL1
End

CREATE TABLE #TBL1
(

 ID int,
InspPost nvarchar (MAX),
InspPostHin nvarchar(MAX)

)
SET @SQLQuery ='INSERT into #TBL1 ([ID], [InspPost], [InspPostHin]) VALUES (1, N''Child Development Project Officer'', N''??? ????? ???????? ?????????'')
INSERT into #TBL1 ([ID], [InspPost], [InspPostHin]) VALUES (2, N''Lady Superviser'', N''????? ????????????'')
INSERT into #TBL1 ([ID], [InspPost], [InspPostHin]) VALUES (3, N''Other'', N''???? ?????'')
INSERT into #TBL1 ([ID], [InspPost], [InspPostHin]) VALUES (4, N''District Program Officer'', N''???? ????????? ?????????'')
INSERT into #TBL1 ([ID], [InspPost], [InspPostHin]) VALUES (5, N''J.P.C/State Level Officer'',N''??.??.??../???? ???????? ????? ?????? ???????'')
INSERT into #TBL1 ([ID], [InspPost], [InspPostHin]) VALUES (6, N''S.P.M.U/Technical Consultant'', N''??.??..??.??. - ?????? ???????'')
INSERT into #TBL1 ([ID], [InspPost], [InspPostHin]) VALUES (7, N''District Coordinator'', N''???? ???????'')
INSERT into #TBL1 ([ID], [InspPost], [InspPostHin]) VALUES (8, N''Project Coordinator'', N''?????? ???????'')
INSERT into #TBL1 ([ID], [InspPost], [InspPostHin]) VALUES (9, N''Swasth Bharat Prerak'', N''?????? ???? ??????'')'

exec (@SQLQuery)
select * from 
(
    select Districtmaster.DistrictID,ProjectMaster.ProjectID,Districtmaster.DistrictNameHn,ProjectMaster.ProjectNameHn from Districtmaster Districtmaster 
    inner join ProjectMaster ProjectMaster on Districtmaster.DistrictID=ProjectMaster.DistID

) a1
inner join
(
  select Supervision_Checklist.ID,Supervision_Checklist.Inspector_Name,
  Supervision_Checklist.DistrictID,Supervision_Checklist.ProjectID,
  Supervision_Checklist.Inspector_Type,(#TBL1.InspPost) as inptype ,Supervision_Checklist.Month
  from Supervision_Checklist Supervision_Checklist 
  inner join #TBL1 #TBL1 
  on Supervision_Checklist.Inspector_Type=#TBL1.ID
) src on a1.DistrictID=src.DistrictID and a1.ProjectID=src.ProjectID 
pivot (count(id) for Month in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) piv
```

i want result as following...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVUU7.png)

Comment: I assume the last 12 columns of your result are the 1-12 columns produced by the `pivot`. Can you translate the first 5 column headings please (how they match up with the query shown here isn't necessarily obvious to all)

Comment: Declaring an alias that is the same as your table's name is pointless by the way. The point of an alias is to provide a succinct name for your objects. So for `Supervision_Checklist` a good alias might be `SC`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the districtid and projectid are the district and project where the inspection happen, inspector type is post of the inspector,and the inspector name is the name of inspector

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the advice.. but my error is something else . if you can help me out with this it would be good...

Comment: Just don't use SELECT *. Since both queries output a DistrictID, SQL Server is just telling you to pick one. You can't do that with *.

Comment: My comment was helpful advice, which will help you in the future write better SQL, not to answer the question. Writing readable and well formatted SQL is a must if you're learning or working with SQL. Not aliasong long table names (which is effectively what you've done here) and a lack of white space and line breaks makes your SQL far harder to read than it should be, which will put volunteers of from answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

A `PIVOT` effectively performs a `GROUP BY` on all columns which are *currently in the result set* and which *aren't* mentioned in the pivot.

If you've done a bit of joining, it's highly likely (as here) that you'll end up with multiple columns of the same name (`DistrictID`). Even though we know that both `DistrictID` values are equal on every row, the optimizer doesn't, and generates this error.

What we need to do is project away the columns that we don't want included in this grouping operation. But there's no convenient way to express this "inline". We need to have a `SELECT` clause and we need the `PIVOT` to be on the "other side" of that `SELECT` clause.

Typically, we'd do this using a subquery or CTE:

```
;With AllResults as (
    select
      id,
      month,
      /* We cannot use * here. We need only those columns needed by the pivot
         or which should appear in the final result */
    from 
    (
        select Districtmaster.DistrictID,ProjectMaster.ProjectID,Districtmaster.DistrictNameHn,ProjectMaster.ProjectNameHn from Districtmaster Districtmaster 
        inner join ProjectMaster ProjectMaster on Districtmaster.DistrictID=ProjectMaster.DistID

    ) a1
    inner join
    (
      select Supervision_Checklist.ID,Supervision_Checklist.Inspector_Name,
      Supervision_Checklist.DistrictID,Supervision_Checklist.ProjectID,
      Supervision_Checklist.Inspector_Type,(#TBL1.InspPost) as inptype ,Supervision_Checklist.Month
      from Supervision_Checklist Supervision_Checklist 
      inner join #TBL1 #TBL1 
      on Supervision_Checklist.Inspector_Type=#TBL1.ID
    ) src on a1.DistrictID=src.DistrictID and a1.ProjectID=src.ProjectID 
)
select *
from AllResults
pivot (count(id) for Month in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) piv
```

Comment: `AllResults` is the CTE introduced on the first line of this query.